# Turn thinkpad screen off and back on automatically via cron

Tags: 14.04, cron, thinkpad

I setup my thinkpad a while back with ubuntu 10.10 to work as a digital picture frame and each night turn off the screen with a cron cron command, then in the morning another cron command turns it back on. Sadly the hard drive died. Luckily I had a spare drive laying around so I put ubuntu 14.10.1 on it but the same command doesn't work. Here's what I use:

#### Screen OFF command - This command works, screen goes off like it should

```
/usr/bin/xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

#### Screen ON command - This command does NOT work --my screen stays OFF

```
/usr/bin/xset -display :0.0 dpms force on
```

It's an R50 and I have an external monitor hooked up to the vga port. This has been a great digital picture frame and has run for years. I have the monitor mounted under a beautiful custom made frame, mounted to the wall and the laptop hides in the closed behind the wall. Help me make this thing turn on again by itself in the morning.